# iO6 CLGeocoder: Always returns only ONE object

Tags: geocoding, ios6-maps, apple-maps

In the code below, I always get only one Object back from geocode NSArray *placemarks.  I do an NSLog it always shows up as one Object.  No matter what I type in the searchBar.

I'm testing it on my iPhone 5 device.  I live in San Francisco and the device Maps work just fine.  i.e. When I type 'Starbucks' I get a only one Object back and it's called "Álvaro Obregón, The Federal District 01020"  There are at least 10 Starbucks within the vicinity.

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {

    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:searchString completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error)

  if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Number of objects in placemarks %i",placemarks.count);
        for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
        {
            self.street = aPlacemark.thoroughfare;
            self.city = aPlacemark.locality;
            self.state = aPlacemark.administrativeArea;
            self.zip = aPlacemark.postalCode;

            NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
            if (self.street)
                [result appendString:self.street];
            if (self.street && (self.city || self.state || self.zip))
                [result appendString:@", "];
            if (self.city)
                [result appendString:self.city];
            if (self.city && self.state)
                [result appendString:@", "];
            if (self.state)
                [result appendString:self.state];
            if (self.zip)
                [result appendFormat:@" %@", self.zip];
            placemarksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [self.placemarksArray addObject:result];
            NSLog(@" This is result %@", result);

            [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
        }
    }

} 
 ]; 
return NO;
```

}